# add constrains for button programmatically in my view. swift 4

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, constraints, swift4

I am new to swift and I want to add constrains for the button to be fit for all screens. The position of the button is top-right in view. To be specific the button appears on google map.

first when I add a button without constrains it appear normally:

valid code:

`let navigationBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 350, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
            navigationBtn.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            navigationBtn.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
            navigationBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            navigationBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "map.png"), for: .normal)
            self.view.addSubview(navigationBtn)`

then I try this code to be sure that my button is fit, but when I run the simulator the button is disappear. I used the following code:

```
  let navigationBtn = UIButton()
        navigationBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "map.png"), for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBtn)

        navigationBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        navigationBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        navigationBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        navigationBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

I am not sure whats wrong. Also, are these method in the above used to achieve my goal?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constraint makes it out screen as currently right_of_button = right_of_screen + 80  only 20 pts will be shown as width of it is 100

```
  navigationBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
```

it should be if say it's 20 pts from the right of the screen

```
  navigationBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

make it off screen

Comment: thank you it works with me. one more question thats mean now my button position is fit to all screens?

Comment: it will fit in all screens but the problem is that the constant won't change it will be 80 from top and 20 from right for all devices which will have a different look say in comparison with iphone 4 and 8 plus

Comment: you can detect current device and set the constant accordingly